# Defining a graph in prolog and checking a list with edges

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

Im extremely new to Prolog and managed to define a graph

[image]

the prolog code I have so far is

```
edge(1,2).
edge(1,3).
edge(2,3).
edge(3,4).
edge(4,6).
edge(6,5).
edge(5,3).
edge(5,1).
```

im trying to figure out how to write a walk/2 predicate that checks that W is parameter in G(the graph), which should check with edge is connected with another.

so when I check the result

?-edge(G), walk([5,Y,X,6],G) should succeed and set Y=3, X=4.

Comment: you forgot `edge(1,2)`.

Comment: Ah, yeah it was format error, I have fixed now thank you!

Comment: Of course, the interesting bits are about the relation between predicates `ex1/1` and `edge/2`. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Was a typo, apologies, should be edge(G)

Answer (score 0):

`path predicate` collects all the paths possible. It can also be used as you have mentioned.

**Note:** An incorrect Start and End Node will end in Stack limit exceeded.

```
edge(1,2).
edge(1,3).
edge(2,3).
edge(3,4).
edge(4,6).
edge(6,5).
edge(5,3).
edge(5,1).

path(Node,Node,[Node]):-!.
path(StartN,EndN,[StartN|List]):-
    edge(StartN,NextN),
    path(NextN,EndN,List).
```

**Examples:**

```
?- path(5,6,[5, Y, X, 6]).
Y = 3,
X = 4
false

?- path(5,6,Path).
Path = [5, 3, 4, 6]
Path = [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
Path = [5, 1, 3, 4, 6]
```