# Prolog recursive method printing out and returning different things. Possible issue with tail recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I am having trouble with a recursive function in Prolog. The main `expand` function seems to be working fine. But when it reaches the base case when one of the lists is empty it prints out the correct output but then starts executing some things on the Call stack from the recursive calls to the expand function and then finally returns an empty list instead of the printed out list:

I have provided a picture showing the callstack here:

[image: I have provided a picture showing the callstack here]

Running the example:

```ml
expand([0,76,va], [vb,vh,vi,vc], vj, Q). 
[[40,130.55,vb,va],[40,93.85,vh,va],[90,121.62,vi,va],[150,280,vc,va]] 
Q = []
```

As you can see it writes `FinalList` as a list of lists but *returns* an empty list.

Here is the code

```ml
edge(va, vb, 40). % looks for an edge between 2 nodes 
edge(va, vh, 40).
edge(va, vi, 90).
edge(va, vc, 150).
edge(vb, va, 40).
edge(vb, vg, 50).
edge(vb, vc, 80).
edge(vb, vd, 110).
edge(vc, vb, 80).
edge(vc, vf, 80).
edge(vc, va, 150).
edge(vc, vd, 60).
edge(vd, vc, 60).
edge(vd, vb, 110).
edge(vd, ve, 80).
edge(vd, vl, 90).
edge(ve, vd, 80).
edge(ve, vf, 70).
edge(ve, vl, 30).
edge(ve, vm, 90).
edge(vf, ve, 70).
edge(vf, vc, 80).
edge(vf, vk, 110).
edge(vf, vg, 40).
edge(vg, vf, 40).
edge(vg, vb, 50).
edge(vg, vh, 20).
edge(vg, vj, 90).
edge(vh, vg, 20).
edge(vh, va, 40).
edge(vh, vp, 120).
edge(vh, vi, 80).
edge(vi, vh, 80).
edge(vi, va, 90).
edge(vi, vp, 60).
edge(vi, vj, 60).
edge(vj, vi, 60).
edge(vj, vg, 90).
edge(vj, vq, 30).
edge(vj, vk, 60).
edge(vk, vj, 60).
edge(vk, vf, 110).
edge(vk, vn, 30).
edge(vk, vl, 40).
edge(vl, vk, 40).
edge(vl, ve, 30).
edge(vl, vd, 90).
edge(vl, vm, 60).
edge(vm, vl, 60).
edge(vm, ve, 90).
edge(vm, vq, 80).
edge(vm, vn, 60).
edge(vn, vm, 60).
edge(vn, vq, 60).
edge(vn, vk, 30).
edge(vn, vp, 80).
edge(vq, vn, 60).
edge(vq, vj, 30).
edge(vq, vm, 80).
edge(vq, vp, 30).
edge(vp, vq, 30).
edge(vp, vi, 60).
edge(vp, vh, 120).
edge(vp, vn, 80).

coordinate(va, 90, 160). % used for calculating straight line distance 
coordinate(vb, 70, 140).
coordinate(vc, 40, 80).
coordinate(vd, 70, 40).
coordinate(ve, 130, 60).
coordinate(vf, 100, 100).
coordinate(vg, 110, 130).
coordinate(vh, 110, 150).
coordinate(vi, 170, 160).
coordinate(vj, 160, 130).
coordinate(vk, 180, 70).
coordinate(vl, 150, 50).
coordinate(vm, 190, 30).
coordinate(vn, 210, 70).
coordinate(vq, 190, 110).
coordinate(vp, 200, 130).

getedge(V1, V2, Cost) :- edge(V1, V2, Cost).

distancecalc(Xa, Ya, Xb, Yb, Result) :-
       Result is round(100*sqrt((Xa - Xb)*(Xa - Xb) + (Ya - Yb)*(Ya - Yb)))/100.

distanceSL(V1, V2, SLD) :- % calculates the straight line distance 
        coordinate(V1, X1, Y1),
        coordinate(V2, X2, Y2),
        distancecalc(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, SLD).
        
sum(X,Y,Z):- Z is X+Y. % Adds 2 numbers

append_list([], L2, L2). % base case when the 2 list are the same

append_list([X | L1], L2, [X | L3]) :- % adds an element from the 1st list
                  % to the last list and calls append without this element 
    append_list(L1, L2, L3).

expand(_A, [], _Goal, FinalList ):- % base case when the NodeList that
                                    % is being expanded is empty
    write(FinalList).  % print out what is in the value of finalList 

expand([Pcost1, PHcost1, Head | Tail], [Node|RemainingNodes], Goal, Ret) :- 
   % Case when there is an edge between the head of the list and 
   % the 1st element in the node list 
       edge(Head, Node,W),
       sum(Pcost1, W, Pcost2),
       distanceSL(Node,Goal,SLD),
       sum(SLD, Pcost2, PHcost2),
       A=[Pcost2, PHcost2, Node, Head | Tail],
       append_list(Ret , [A], FinalList),
       expand([Pcost1, PHcost1, Head | Tail], RemainingNodes, Goal, FinalList).  
           %calling expand with the tail of the node list

expand([Pcost1, PHcost1, Head | Tail], [Node|RemainingNodes], Goal, Ret):-
            % case when there is no edge between the head and the head of  
            % the list. Therefore there is nothing to expand 
      not(edge(Head, Node,_W)),
      expand([Pcost1, PHcost1, Head | Tail], RemainingNodes, Goal, Ret).
```

(https://onlinegdb.com/Xi_Rli8bM)

I tried step debugging and I am very confused as to why it goes backwards to the past `expand` calls. I feel like what I have is tail recursive but the way it is going back to past `expand` methods maybe not.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: The issue that expand will return an empty list instead of the list of lists that expand calculates @false

Comment: Tried removing your 3rd `expand` predicate? What's its purpose?

Comment: The 3rd expand is for when there is no edge between the 2 nodes that expand is looking at. I will clarify what is happening in the code in the original post @brebs

Comment: I think your `expand` should look more like `path` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67291879/